# PHP - Empy an array if there is only one ch aracter type is left

Tags: php

I need to check if there are only comas and spaces left in array and if that is the case to empty or destroy array. How can I do this?

For example I have an array like this:

```
$array = (, , , ,)
```

Comment: I suppose you mean `$array = array(',', ' ', ' ', ',');`. No ?

Comment: @Magus in my case comas and spaces are left overs of array_slice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at **my function:**

```
// my magic function
function array_contains_only(&$array, &$matches) {
    $tmp = 0;

    // loop through array
    foreach($array as $key => $val) {
        // check if value matches one of the matches
        // if so, increment $tmp
        if(in_array($val, $matches)) $tmp++;
    }

    // check if $tmp equals the length of $array,
    // if so, the array contains $matches only
    return (count($array) === $tmp);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
// dummy arrays
$demo1 = array(' ', ',', ' ', ',', ',');
$demo1 = array(' ', ',', ' ', ',', ',', '123');

// characters to match
$chars = array(' ', ',');

// check $demo1
if(array_contains_only($demo1, $chars)) $demo1 = array(); // create new array

// check $demo2
if(array_contains_only($demo2, $chars)) $demo2 = array(); // create new array

print_r($demo1); // new, empty array
print_r($demo2); // old array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

$result = array_filter(
    $array,
    function ($value) {
        return !is_null($value);
    }
);

var_dump($result);
```